# How Can I Prevent PHP SoapClient From Converting Double Value to Scientific Notation?

Tags: php, soap-client, scientific-notation

I'm using the PHP SoapClient and passing a credit card number as one of the values.  This number is getting converted to exponential format by the soapCall method.  I'm passing 4321432143274321 and the server is getting `<ccNumber xsi:type="xsd:double">4.3214321432743E+15</ccNumber>`.  I've tried casting the value as a double and a string to no avail.

I cannot find any hints on this issue anywhere!  The closest I have found is this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#75078, but the "fix" isn't really a fix.

Here's my code:

```
    private function SetUpClient()
    {
        try
        {
            $options = array( 
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE
            );

            $auth->username = $this->_username;
            $auth->password = $this->_password;

            $authValues = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
            $header =  new SoapHeader("http://v1.webservices", "authentication", $authValues, false);

            $this->_soapClient = new SoapClient( $this->_wsdlUrl );
            $this->_soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
        }
        catch( Exception $ex )
        {
            var_dump($ex);
            return "An error occured: " .  $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function CallWebService($methodName, $arguments)
    {
        try {
            $result = $this->_soapClient->__soapCall($methodName, $arguments);
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $result = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Here's the $arguments array being passed:

```
    Array
    (
            [memberUid] => 123456789
            [items] => 1809,1,N,1821,1,N
            [shippingOption] => 40
            [name1] => Test15, Juan
            [name2] => 
            [address1] => 123 Test Street
            [address2] => 
            [address3] => 
            [address4] => 
            [city] => Anytown
            [stateCode] => NY
            [countryCode] => USA
            [postalCode] => 12345
            [subOrderType] => 041
            [entryDate] => 08/18/2011
            [ccType] => 3
            [ccHolder] => Juan Test
            [ccNumber] => 4321432143274321
            [ccExpDate] => 01/2014
            [externalOrderNumber] => 
            [orderSource] => 
    )
```

And finally the section of the soap call the server is seeing:

```
    <ns1:createOrder>
        <memberUid xsi:type="xsd:string">123456789</memberUid>
        <items xsi:type="xsd:string">1809,1,N,1821,1,N</items>
        <shippingOption xsi:type="xsd:double">40</shippingOption>
        <name1 xsi:type="xsd:string">Test, Juan</name1>
        <name2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        <address1 xsi:type="xsd:string">123 Test Street</address1>
        <address2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        <address3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        <address4 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        <city xsi:type="xsd:string">Anytown</city>
        <stateCode xsi:type="xsd:string">NY</stateCode>
        <countryCode xsi:type="xsd:string">USA</countryCode>
        <postalCode xsi:type="xsd:string">12345</postalCode>
        <subOrderType xsi:type="xsd:string">041</subOrderType>
        <entryDate xsi:type="xsd:string">08/19/2011</entryDate>
        <ccType xsi:type="xsd:double">3</ccType>
        <ccHolder xsi:type="xsd:string">Juan Test</ccHolder>
        <ccNumber xsi:type="xsd:double">4.3214321432743E+15</ccNumber>
        <ccExpDate xsi:type="xsd:string">01/2014</ccExpDate>
        <externalOrderNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
        <orderSource xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
    </ns1:createOrder>
```

Comment: I found a couple of similar issues:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43053 (I'm using PHP 5.3.4)
http://www.jitterbit.com/PhpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&p=7319#p7317

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

I updated the "precision" setting in the php.ini file.  I increased that value from 14 to 16.  Sixteen digits is the max I need for credit card numbers.  Adjust to your needs accordingly!

Comment: It's probably best to simply use ini_set("precision", "16"); instead of changing the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your ccNumber to a string to prevent serialization from using the floating point representation.

```
[ccNumber] => 4321432143274321 . ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) function to convert the number to string exactly. By default, it uses a comma as thousands separator. To avoid this, you have to explicitly override it:

```
$ccNumber = number_format( 4321432143274321, 0, '', '' );
```

Comment: This is no different than simply casting as a string.

The number is being passed to the __soapCall() intact.  I'm confident that it's something in the __soapCall() that's doing the converting.